# SSRS Report Builder 3.0 - Why can't I use a code function as the source expression of a Lookup Function?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I've built a report in Report Builder 3.0 that has a couple of hundred cells that perform Lookup functions in my datasets.  Obviously, with the number of cells, I would like to be able to create the expressions dynamically. I've been able to utilize the textbox names to do this with the following function:

```
Public Function TextBoxName(ByVal meString As String) As String
 Dim s As Integer = 19
 Dim e As Integer = meString.IndexOf(“_TextBoxExprHost”) – 19
 TextBoxName = meString.Substring(s,e)
 End Function

Expression:
 =Code.TextBoxName(Me.ToString)
```

The above expression works as needed everywhere in the report except when I want to use it in a source expression in a Lookup function.  Here is an example:

```
Iif(IsNothing(Lookup((Code.TextBoxName(Me.ToString) & "R"),Fields!SECTION_STATUS.Value,Fields!LCTN_COUNT.Value, "Loads")),"0",Lookup((Code.TextBoxName(Me.ToString) & "R"),Fields!SECTION_STATUS.Value,Fields!LCTN_COUNT.Value, "Loads"))
```

The above example will compile but produces a #Error in the cell when I run the report. But, the report works as needed if I hardcode the textbox name for each of the source expressions.

```
"AP1010R" instead of Code.TextBoxName(Me.ToString) & "R"
```

I've found no examples of anyone using custom code to generate this source expression.  Anyone have any ideas what could be going on here?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually not with the custom code in the source expression (try a simple custom function that only returns a string and it works fine), but specifically with the `Me.ToString` portion.  My guess is `Me` is trying to reference the wrong object while inside the Lookup.

I haven't found much detailed usage for `Me`, but a possible workaround would be writing your own custom lookup function which is detailed nicely in [this MSDN forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a7d59224-0ee5-491e-883b-2e5fcb3edeab/iterate-through-rows-of-dataset-in-reports-custom-code).  The gist of it (using [Lookup function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx) terminology):

1. Create a hidden, multi-value parameter
2. Set available and default values to destination_expression column; set labels to result_expression column
3. Add custom code:

   ```
   Function CustomLookup(id AS String) AS String
     Dim i As Integer
     i = 0
     For i = 1 to Report.Parameters!YourParameter.Count()
       If Report.Parameters!YourParameter.Value(i) = id Then
         CustomLookup = Report.Parameters!YourParameter.Label(i)
         Exit For
       End If
     Next i
   End Function
   ```
4. Call it like: `=Code.CustomLookup(Code.TextBoxName(Me.ToString) & "R")`

This may not be feasible/performant enough (especially if your lookup dataset is large and/or destination and result expression columns change a lot in various lookups) but it could work well in some scenarios.